# Revert #line directive in C/C++ file

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to generate C/C++ files in which I would like to overwrite the line number and file name in a specific region of code.

Consider the following minimal example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    #line 50 "inserted"
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __FILE__ << std::endl;
    #line 6 "main.cpp"
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __FILE__ << std::endl;
}
```

after compiling and executing will output:

```
50 inserted
6 main.cpp
```

In the above example I am overriding the line and the file using the #line directive so that they have a custom value during the first print.
I would like now to have in the 2nd print the "correct" line and file number, i.e. the ones that would be there if the #line directive was not used at all.

In the example above I am manually resetting the line and file name by hard coding the correct value.

Is there any way to have the preprocessor automatically revert a previous #line directive to have the original line and file name?

Comment: I don't think there is.

Comment: Seems this has been asked before with no good answers. If against the odds someone does come up with an answer, please post it below the linked duplicate.

Comment: `#line` is intended to be used by code generators, not by humans.

Comment: I am writing the code generator...

Comment: A code generator needs to keep track of lines anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to reset the `#line` directive.
There might be an advanced trick to store the previous state though, but I coudln't find it.

If you have access to C++20 there is [source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) which should allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible for a reason similar to why `BAR` prints 3 and 4, instead of 3 and 3, in the following example.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    #define FOO 3   // say this is my __LINE__
    #define BAR FOO // which I try to remember
    std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
    #undef FOO     // with these two lines
    #define FOO 4  // I'm the preprocessor that increments __LINE__
    std::cout << BAR << std::endl; // but this sees the new value of __LINE__
}
```

So it's probably not possible to store the old value of `__LINE__`. Doing it would seem like a runtime thing...